# Cannot seed from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

```
ContactGroup::all()->each(function ($contactGroup) {
    $contactGroup->manyMessage()->save(factory(MessageMod::class, 10)->create());
});
```

I want to seed from populated pivot table (contact_group table with model named ContactGroup) to child table (messages table with model named MessageMod) but got 
`Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.`

it logs:

```
insert into messages (content_text, level, sentiment_result, updated_at, created_at) values (Sunt tempore nihil suscipit et maiores ducimus. Unde tempora quo quo. Ipsum officia perspiciatis perspiciatis provident dolor qui odit., 0, 2, 2019-11-21 23:13:42, 2019-11-21 23:13:42)
```

while it should have been:

```
insert into messages (content_text, level, sentiment_result, updated_at, created_at, contact_group_id) values (Sunt tempore nihil suscipit et maiores ducimus. Unde tempora quo quo. Ipsum officia perspiciatis perspiciatis provident dolor qui odit., 0, 2, 2019-11-21 23:13:42, 2019-11-21 23:13:42, 1)
```

notice the latter there is `contact_group_id` field in the Insert SQL statement.
If I run the latter manually on SQL console, it works. but the first one fails in terminal as well as SQL console

ContactGroup Model:

```
class ContactGroup extends Model
{
    protected $table = "contact_group";
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function manyMessage()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MessageMod::class, 'contact_group_id');
    }
}
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `factory()` usage, but I believe this line `factory(MessageMod::class, 10)->create()` creates a record in the database and is unaware of `$contactGroup` at that point. It's wrapped in a `save()` method for `$contactGroup->manyMessage()`, but that approach likely won't work here, or it it did, might create duplicate data in your database. Manually, you could set `$messageMod->contact_group_id = $contactGroup->id`, then `$messageMod->save()`, but again, not sure how you'd do this with `factory()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself

I must add nullable to the migration.